# SearchView widget never launches Searchable results activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I am trying to implement a SearchView widget into my application.

**The problem:** When I press search, my Searchable activity is never launched to display the results. The SearchView widget is not being linked to the results activity for some reason.

Here is the relevant code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!--ACTIVITY WITH SEARCHVIEW WIDGET-->
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LocationManagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location_manager" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".activity.LocationManagerResultsActivity" />
    </activity>

<!--ACTIVITY TO DISPLAY RESULTS-->
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LocationManagerResultsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location_manager_results" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.search" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

LocationManagerActivity.class

```
public class LocationManagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_manager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_location_manager, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.location_manager_menu_search));

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, LocationManagerResultsActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));

    return true;
}

}
```

LocationManagerResultsActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_manager_results);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "have intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(query);
    }
}
```

The LocationManagerResultsActivity is never actually created by the LocationManagerActivity SearchView.

I've done everything I could find on all other questions

- add `default_searchable` to the base activity
- add `android.app.searchable` and `@xml/searchable` to the searchable activity
- change `getComponentName()` to get the searchable activity's component name

In other words, I can type things in to the search bar, but when I press search, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not capitalize the name of the search intent filter properly.

What used to be:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.search" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is now:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
```

That fixed all of my problems.